# Hiding the vertical scrollbar when overflow-x is hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

In this example, I need to hide content horizontally with overflow-x set to hidden. However, it is also automatically adding the vertical scrollbar when I do this. I have read where setting overflow-x or overflow-y sets the other to auto, thus forcing the scrollbar to show. Is there a way around this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
    </div>
</div>

div.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

div.div2 {
    width: 600px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

div.div3 {
    width: 90px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Why not set *overflow-y: hidden;* to *div1*?

Comment: Because if the content in div3 grows vertically, it has to be shown. I want the Y to just grow without scrollbars.

Comment: what do u wana do..do u want to completely hide the scroll bars?

Comment: I want content in div2 hidden horizontally but content in div3 to grow vertically without any scrollbars. So yes, no scrollbars should be shown at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height on div.div1 so div can grow in height.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you want hide everything overflowing horizontal. But you want `.div1` to stretch vertically when more content is added?

If so, change the CSS to:

```
div.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/7/).

Or, if you want to keep `.div1` with a fixed height, change `overflow-y` to `auto`. Check [with small content](http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/8/) and [with long content](http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/9/).

Answer (score 0):

You could remove x & y scrollbar with :

```
div.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give `width :100%` to show the full content horizontally

```
 div.div1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #000;
        overflow-y: visible;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: No, div1 must be limited in width.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be fix the problem :

```
div.div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```